# I want to display selected item with some title in Spinner,Like item is:item6

Tags: android

I am new in android ,I want work like, In Spinner if i select any other items form array,that item should get selected including with some text,For example,if My spinner having 10 items,if i select 6th item that item should display like "Your Item Is: Item6",This should be display in my spinner as first item,After select of items form the array,Please help  me ,,Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] categories = {"Select one","Automobile","Computers","Education"};

  // Creating adapter for spinner
  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

  // attaching data adapter to spinner
  spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

then onItemSelected Listerner Do :-

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  // On selecting a spinner item
  String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
  categories[0] = item;
  ArrayAdapter<String> newdataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
  spinner.setAdapter(newdataAdapter);

  }
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = null;
String[] list=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //you can replace the below list with your list
    list = {"Mercury","Venus","Earth","Mars","Jupiter","Saturn","Uranus","Neptune","Pluto"};
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            spinner.setPrompt("Your selected item is:"+list[position]);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```